# I changed thermostat now there is a loud noise

Tags: noise, overheating, thermostat

I recently had the upper radiator hose blow out. I replaced it. No problems. 2 weeks later I started experiencing over heating/temp gauge going up and down but never redlining, but once in which case I shutdown vehicle and let cool then made it to destination no more than a mile away. 2 days later scheduled to see mechanic to change thermostat. After when starting engine, I heard a loud clunking noise. What could possibly be the issue? No prior issues other than forementioned.

Comment: I suspect the two issues are not related.  Does this happen only when starting the vehicle or is there a clunking sound when you put it into gear or when driving down the road?

Comment: Have you checked your coolant level recently?